# Jenkins build says successful but no output is seen?

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I am deploying my reactjs application. For which I have written pipeline script to deploy on EC2 Server from Jenkins.

Every time build is successful but no output is coming. I am unable to find the error.
When I login to EC2 instance through putty and when i am deploying the application manually then application is running but same steps when i written in pipeline and executing then output is not coming

I have checked in several ways but no use

This is the simple Jenkins file I am using as I am directly deploying in to server because i am checking the error

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'master'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') { 
            agent {
                label 'testnode'
            }
            steps {
               script{
                    
                    sh """
                        #!/bin/bash
                        ls
                        sudo npm start &
                    """
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Console Output**

```
Started by user Mani
Replayed #18
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/caches/git-02fb4007d201f8b81dff24c4385bb601/.git # timeout=10
Setting origin to https://ManiGopal27@bitbucket.org/nariyapratik/econote-web.git
 > git config remote.origin.url https://ManiGopal27@bitbucket.org/nariyapratik/econote-web.git # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.32.0'
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 1 remote branch
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 95b8c92cd4dab7a9e6e8d13c81c84bca700dbe36
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/React_master
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: git
using credential Bitbucket
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/React_master/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://ManiGopal27@bitbucket.org/nariyapratik/econote-web.git # timeout=10
Fetching without tags
Fetching upstream changes from https://ManiGopal27@bitbucket.org/nariyapratik/econote-web.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.32.0'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://ManiGopal27@bitbucket.org/nariyapratik/econote-web.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 95b8c92cd4dab7a9e6e8d13c81c84bca700dbe36 (master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 95b8c92cd4dab7a9e6e8d13c81c84bca700dbe36 # timeout=10
Commit message: "Jenkinsfile edited online with Bitbucket"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 95b8c92cd4dab7a9e6e8d13c81c84bca700dbe36 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] node
Running on testnode in /home/ec2-user/workspace/React_master
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
The recommended git tool is: git
using credential Bitbucket
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching without tags
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /home/ec2-user/workspace/React_master/.git # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://ManiGopal27@bitbucket.org/nariyapratik/econote-web.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://ManiGopal27@bitbucket.org/nariyapratik/econote-web.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.32.0'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket
 > git fetch --no-tags --force --progress -- https://ManiGopal27@bitbucket.org/nariyapratik/econote-web.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 95b8c92cd4dab7a9e6e8d13c81c84bca700dbe36 (master)
Commit message: "Jenkinsfile edited online with Bitbucket"
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls
Jenkinsfile
node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
public
README.md
serve.json
src
webpack.config.js
yarn.lock
+ sudo npm start
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS


total 39416
    drwxrwxrwx    6 ec2-user ec2-user      265 Jun 21 05:19 .
    drwxrwxr-x    6 ec2-user ec2-user      100 Jun 20 09:19 ..
    -rw-rw-r--    1 ec2-user ec2-user       25 Jun 21 05:14 .env
    drwxrwxrwx    8 ec2-user ec2-user      162 Jun 21 05:20 .git
    -rw-rw-r--    1 ec2-user ec2-user      503 Jun 21 05:14 .gitignore
    -rw-rw-r--    1 ec2-user ec2-user      797 Jun 21 05:14 Jenkinsfile
    drwxrwxrwx 1280 ec2-user ec2-user    40960 Jun 15 17:58 node_modules
    -rw-rw-r--    1 ec2-user ec2-user     3429 Jun 21 05:14 package.json
    -rw-rw-r--    1 ec2-user ec2-user  1070508 Jun 21 05:14 package-lock.json
    drwxrwxrwx    4 ec2-user ec2-user      105 Jun 21 05:14 public
    -rw-rw-r--    1 ec2-user ec2-user     4397 Jun 21 05:14 README.md
    -rw-rw-r--    1 ec2-user ec2-user      285 Jun 21 05:14 serve.json
    drwxrwxrwx    5 ec2-user ec2-user      101 Jun 21 05:14 src
    -rw-rw-r--    1 ec2-user ec2-user     1784 Jun 21 05:14 webpack.config.js
    -rwxrwxrwx    1 root     root       653925 Jun 15 17:56 yarn.lock
    + sudo npm start
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // script
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // withEnv
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // withEnv
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    Finished: SUCCESS
```

When i deploy the application with same command (sudo npm run start) manually by logging in to EC2 server then it is running and i am seeing the output but from Jenkins i am facing this problem.

Can anyone please help how to solve this ?

Comment: As per your pipeline, you are executing your npm command on the Jenkins `label 'master'`. Is this where you want to start the server?

Comment: You can check the user permission which is trying to run `npm start &` command. If the user lets say is jenkins, please check if it has correct permission to execute npm commands with sudo.

Comment: Hi @ycr can you please check pipeline again ? I have mentioned label 'testnode' under deploy stage ... this is where i am executing npm command to start the server

Comment: Thank you @Sourav for your suggestion , will check that and update

Comment: `npm start &` you run your app in background, so you can't see the app log directly from  where `npm start &` executed.  You can try to remove `&`, then you can see app log , but in this way, your Jenkins pipeline will not end.

Comment: Hi Yong, i have checked that too without & but same problem i am facing  and here problem is pipeline is getting success with or without & this

Comment: hello @Sourav I have checked but it's not working
I have added that output also along with cosole ouput ...check in last
thank you

Comment: @ManiGopalSettibathula Ok. Another thing you can try by adding the `node.js`  bin/ folder path under **Manage Jenkins >> Manage Nodes & Clouds >> testnode >> Configure >> Node Properties >> Select the Tool Locations >> Click on Add >> Under Name (select nodejs) >> Under Home, give nodejs path**

If you cannot see the nodejs, you need to install the NodeJs Jenkins plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs/

Then, Try to run `npm --version` from pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `jenkins` pipeline always execute `npm` commands with "run"

```
ex - npm run start / npm run test / npm run lint
```